# Is there an Mathematica version of Structural Mechanics Solver Based on symbol system?

Tags: symbolic, physics

I want to write a structural mechanic's solver similar to the following one. The difference is that only numerical parameters are accepted below. I want to write a symbolic solver system with the help of MMA. Is there relevant resource for my work?

[image]

In other words, I want to rewrite this structural mechanic's solver with MMA based on symbolic computing system, but I don't know how to start. I hope you can provide some relevant examples for reference.

Comment: `Is there relevant materials for my work?` this is really a vague question. What exactly are you asking for here? If you want examples, then Wolfram demo site has of demos many examples on the subject. There was also a structural mechanics application but no longer offered. https://reference.wolfram.com/applications/structural/IntroductiontoStructuralMechanics.html  You could always write your own using Manipulate also. `but I don't know how to start` as always, you start with the equations themselves and go from there. This is no different than any other app.

Comment: Here is the PDF for the old Mathematica structural mechanics application http://media.wolfram.com/brochures/structuralspecsheet.pdf  Wolfram used to sell many applications like this long time ago, but it seems they stopped all these for some reason.

Comment: @Nasser Its help documentation is based on obsolete version 4.0. And I don't know where to download these packages.